# Response Code 302 not getting displayed in console during runtime but gets displayed in debug mode using Selenium devTools for chrome browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

Need some help in knowing why I am seeing different console output/logs during runtime and debug time in the automation framework.  Using selenium dev tools dependency, I have managed to capture response 302 in debug mode, but 302 do not getting displayed in console/log during runtime mode. Seems I am missing some configuration in chrome dev tools to enable network logs using selenium devtools during runtime. Not sure what and where.

In Debug mode, I see following output showing 302 but not during runtime

INFO: <- {"method":"Network.responseReceivedExtraInfo","params":{"requestId":"BABA0D5682BA50EB143A5DF45AD69CBB","blockedCookies":[],"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Cache-Control":"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0","Content-Length":"0","Date":"Mon, 15 Jan 2024 01:43:46 GMT","Expires":"-1","Location":"/update-action-prf/qaa_wf_lyd_payables_tenant/paymentrequest-
confirm/ckcrN3dMWEVYRU5YQVBxZjFTMHJSdG1XRHlrSjQrZTJSQWNWQzRZZTZ6Yz0%3D","Pragma":"no-cache","X-Robots-Tag":"noindex","X-XSS-Protection":"1; mode=block"},"resourceIPAddressSpace":"Private","statusCode":302,"headersText":"HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nDate: Mon, 15 Jan 2024 01:43:46 GMT\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nCache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0\r\nExpires: -1\r\nLocation:

In terms of logging, I have following config in serenity.config file

```
 perfLoggingPrefs {
    enableNetwork: true,
    enablePage: true,
    traceCategories: "browser,devtools.timeline,devtools"
  }

  excludeSwitches = ["enable-automation", "load-extension"]

}

"goog:loggingPrefs" {
  browser = ALL
  driver = ALL
  performance = ALL
}
```

and ChromeOptions.java class contains following code

```
@Override
public void apply(EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables, ChromiumOptions\<?\> options) {
HashMap\<String, Object\> chromePrefs = new HashMap\<String, Object\>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", DOWNLOAD_FOLDER);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.javascript", ENABLEJS);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

}

Comparing runtime and debugger console, have noticed following INFO gets logged only during debug time but not during runtime. What config am I missing here? Any help on this will be very much appreciated?

```
Jan 14, 2024 2:40:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection 
handle
INFO: Method Network.requestWillBeSent called with 2 callbacks 
available
Jan 14, 2024 2:40:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection 
lambda$handle$3
INFO: Matching Network.requestWillBeSent with 
Network.responseReceived
Jan 14, 2024 2:40:44 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection 
lambda$handle$3
INFO: Matching Network.requestWillBeSent with Network.requestWillBeSent
```

So far, I have tried this

1. Making sure all browser, performance and driver logs were enabled and set to ALL in serenity.conf
2. Try running test in browser mode as well as in headless mode
3. Adding thread.sleep just in case if there was not enough time to log the entries
4. Adding --verbose in goog:chromeOptions in serenity.conf